# Sharepoint zero touch deployment

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

We are developing a solution based on sharepoint, the solution also contains a custom database and WCF services.

What we would like to do is to deploy once a day to the test environment. Preferably 100% automated.

Has anyone managed to do this? Is there anything special to look out for?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use curise Control to Build the wsp.

cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

And then we use a bat file that uses stsadm to deploy the wsp. you can pakage the database scripts within the wsp